# ArXive file, how do I read the source?

Tags: pdftex, winedt, text

I have an important file [here](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1907.00284) but I do not know how do I extract it so that I can read it in WinEdt 9. I have Win 8.1.
What (at best signed one) file should I download and install to unzip it?
What filename extension should I give to the file now named 1907.00284 ?
I need a plain file named .tex at the end.

Comment: Just unzip it in some directory. It contains a file with extension .tex and another with extension .bbl (an auxiliary file used for the bibliography).

Comment: unzip just outputs this error message: End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in 1907.00284,
        and cannot find 1907.00284.zip, period.

Comment: I've typed "unzip 1907.00284"

Comment: I had no problem with 7-zip.

Comment: @Bernard Perhaps I should rename 1907.00284 first ?

Comment: You've deleted its name??

Comment: I have downloaded 1907.00284 which was saved **without** file extension. I thought that the error above is due to this.

Comment: 7-zip detects it's a compressed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the file `1907.00284` to `1907.00284.tar.gz` and then use a decompression tool of your choice, e.g. 7-zip is very good for windows

If you have linux subsystems installed:

```
tar -xzvf 1907.00284.tar.gz
```